# Bike parts in box are not fixing in one place - html css

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce, css-selectors

I am using `Visual Products Configurator` as per client needs. The product is a bike, and it is divided into 4 parts.

> 1. Bike body
> 2. Front wheel
> 3. Back wheel
> 4. Seat

I am trying to fix them in one place, but when I decrease my window size (responsiveness), it moves to another place. I am using `%` for `width, left & right etc` properties. But it still not fitting in one place.

> Seems like i will have to make a lot of media queries for it?

I am finding a short solution, a better solution.
**Code:**

```css
#vpc-preview {
    padding: 30px;
    position: relative;
}
#vpc-preview img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
#vpc-preview img:first-child {
    max-width: calc(100% - 100px);
    position: relative;
}
#vpc-preview img:nth-child(2) {
    width: 15%;
    left: 34%;
    top: 39%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
#vpc-preview img:nth-child(3) {
    width: 25%;
    inset: auto auto 5px 7%;
}
#vpc-preview img:last-child {
    max-width: 25%;
    inset: auto 15% 5px auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="vpc-preview"><img src="https://pace-bike.hadithapi.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/Body.png" style="z-index:1" data-component-id="component-61c5cd5b45c6d"><img src="https://pace-bike.hadithapi.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/Seat.png" style="z-index:1" data-component-id="component-61c5cd5b1e09c"><img src="https://pace-bike.hadithapi.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/Tire-Front.png" style="z-index:-1" data-component-id="component-61f2bc32489e0"><img src="https://pace-bike.hadithapi.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/Tire-Rear.png" style="z-index:-1" data-component-id="component-61f2bc7c570e7"></div>
```

I am stuck, don't know how to make it perfect so that it works for other screens too. Please help me.

Comment: I suggest SVG, it will perform better and can do all the actions you need

Comment: @LuísP.A. How can svg do these actions?

Comment: What you need? Motion? Click areas? Change? Express your self... Note: https://www.svgator.com/

Comment: @LuísP.A. I just need it responsive

Answer (score -1):

Use one container with 4 areas (seat, tire1, tire2, body).
All your photos should be the same proportion from the start.
Then you position your zones in % and you also adjust their size in % compared to the container.
Only Percent, no Pixel units.

Or use Canvas

Comment: I am using only one container with 4 images and all the sizes are in `%`. Please tell me something new which helps.

Answer (score -1):

You can Also use the margin-bottom, margin-right, margin-left, margin-top to change the position of it